# Angular date filter not working with milliseconds (string or number)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-filter

I have something like this in my view:

```
{{1288323623006 | date:'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'}}
```

But it throws me an error in my console like this:
[image]

When I convert the milliseconds to a date object in my controller, like this:

```
$scope.myDate = new Date(1288323623006);
```

and in my view:

```
{{myDate  | date:'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'}}
```

then it shows `29/10/2010 06:40:23 AM` as expected.

Here is an example from [Angular Docs](https://plnkr.co/edit/RZfqUo8sizVGDsW2XiMj?p=preview) which throws the above error in my console.

I can convert the date to an object and pass it to the view, but I am interested to manage it this way, cause I don't want to use such a fixes.

I haven't change anything in my *I18nAdapter*.

Anyone had similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently solved this issue and now I am posting my solution.

It turned out the angular's filters did not work because of localization's filters which were used instead.

What I did was disabling the localized date filters by commenting these lines inside our `i18n.js` library:

```
angular.module('app.filters.I18nAngular', []).filter('translate', function() {
   return function(key, obj) {
      return i18nAdapter.translate(key, obj);
   };
}).filter('number', function() {
   return function(value, options) {
      return i18nAdapter.formatNumber(value, options);
   };
}).filter('currency', function() {
   return function(value) {
      return i18nAdapter.formatCurrency(value);
   };
});
// .filter('date', function() {
// return function(value, format) {
// return i18nAdapter.formatDate(value, format);
// };
// });
```

The `i18nAdapter` has it's own formatting and filters, similar to angular, but in our case we are just fine using those that angular provides.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom filter and use it with your value like this:

Filter:

```
.filter('millisecondsToDate', function($filter) {
  return function(millseconds) {
    var timeString = $filter('date')(new Date(millseconds),'d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss a');
    return timeString;
  };
})
```

HTML:

```
{{ 1288323623006 | millisecondsToDate }}
```

This will output `29/10/2010 06:40:23 AM`.

**EDIT:**

Actually this works too:

```
{{ 1288323623006 | date: 'd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss a' }}
```

So you just had the date format wrong and that's why Angular can't convert it to a date.

Please see [documentation for AngularJS date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for correct format.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/qrr451pk/

**EDIT 2:**

With i18n have you tried the following?

```
{{ 1288323623006 | date:'short'}}
```

Or with custom formatting:

```
{{ 1288323623006 | date:'d/M/yy h:mm:ss a' }}
```

Comment: I read the documentation. It is not the format. I tried your format too. I said, it works fine when an object is passed in the view to be filtered (formatted), but it does not work when milliseconds are passed

Comment: But it does work perfectly. See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/qrr451pk/

Comment: I know it works perfectly on the fiddle, I even put one in the question. The problem is that localization library is making some issue, so milliseconds passed in the view are not being formated

Comment: it does not work. I will try the custom filter, but even if it works, I am still looking the root of the bare problem, not a work around

Comment: Yeah well it seems like you have something else wrong somewhere in your app. This could be taunting task to debug and would required to see the full code, so I guess I can't really help you. Sorry about that.

Comment: It is ok, thank you for your effort and time. When I got a solution, I'll share it

Comment: No problem at all...I will be interested to see your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying o parse a non-date object. You need to pass the filter a Date object, the same way you are doing in your controller. You should do something like:

```
{{new Date(1288323623006) | date:'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'}}
```

Comment: in the documentation says that you can pass both, milliseconds as a stirng/number or a Date object. And you can see it in action in the plunkr example in the questoin